# Unable to use metasploit framework(I'm using windows 8.1)

Tags: file, rubygems, metasploit

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bcrypt":
In Gemfile:
metasploit-framework x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.102, which depends on bcrypt (=3.1.12) x64-mingw32

Could not find gem 'bcrypt (=3.1.12)', which is required by gem 'metasploit-framework', in any of the sources.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ruby dependency required for Metasploit to run. Simply run `gem install bcrypt` and you should be good to go (unless other dependencies are missing). If you’re using Linux, apt or yum would help you avoid this and automatically install any dependencies along with your desired binary